# order day sql select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, nvarchar

Good Day!
I have a table filled with date time datatype it's stored as nvarchar.
I need to select from the table and get result sorted by day
the day is inserted in this shape.

```
>Thursday 11:30-12:30
>Sunday 08:00-09:00
>Sunday 08:00-09:00
>Sunday 08:00-09:00
>Sunday 08:00-09:00
>Monday 08:00-09:00
>Monday 09:00-10:00
>Monday 08:00-09:00
```

i have tried using this

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Class_Time_ID] ,[Class_ID] ,[Class_Date]
FROM [School].[dbo].[Class_Time_Table] 
ORDER BY CASE Class_Date WHEN 'Monday' THEN 2 
                         WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 3 
                         WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 4 
                         WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 5 
                         WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 1
         end
```

Comment: What is the table schema? What have you tried so far? Have you even made an effort to solve this on your own?

Comment: i have tried using this 
SELECT TOP 1000 [Class_Time_ID]
      ,[Class_ID]
      ,[Class_Date]
  FROM [School].[dbo].[Class_Time_Table]
  ORDER BY 
     CASE Class_Date 
     WHEN 'Monday' THEN 2
     WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 3
     WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 4
     WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 5
     WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 1
  end

Comment: Learn how to ask question if you want to get answer.  Also, what have tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CROSS APPLY` may be helpful as it then permits use of an alias for the `case expression` in both the `select` and `where` clauses. e.g.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65b09/4)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Class_Time_Table
    ([Class_Date] varchar(20), [Class_Time_ID] int ,[Class_ID] int)
;

INSERT INTO Class_Time_Table
    ([Class_Date])
VALUES
    ('Thursday 11:30-12:30'),
    ('Sunday 08:00-09:00'),
    ('Sunday 08:00-09:00'),
    ('Sunday 08:00-09:00'),
    ('Sunday 08:00-09:00'),
    ('Monday 08:00-09:00'),
    ('Monday 09:00-10:00'),
    ('Monday 08:00-09:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
       ctt.*
      , ca.day_of_week,ca.start_time,ca.end_time
FROM Class_Time_Table ctt
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
            CASE
                  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Monday%' THEN 2
                  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Tuesday%' THEN 3
                  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Wednesday%' THEN 4
                  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Thursday%' THEN 5
                  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Sunday%' THEN 1
            END                                    AS day_of_week
          , SUBSTRING(RIGHT(class_date, 11), 1, 5) AS start_time
          , SUBSTRING(RIGHT(class_date, 5) , 1, 5)  AS end_time
  ) ca 
order by day_of_week, start_time, end_time
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65b09/4/0)**:

```
|           Class_Date | Class_Time_ID | Class_ID | day_of_week | start_time | end_time |
|----------------------|---------------|----------|-------------|------------|----------|
|   Sunday 08:00-09:00 |        (null) |   (null) |           1 |      08:00 |    09:00 |
|   Sunday 08:00-09:00 |        (null) |   (null) |           1 |      08:00 |    09:00 |
|   Sunday 08:00-09:00 |        (null) |   (null) |           1 |      08:00 |    09:00 |
|   Sunday 08:00-09:00 |        (null) |   (null) |           1 |      08:00 |    09:00 |
|   Monday 08:00-09:00 |        (null) |   (null) |           2 |      08:00 |    09:00 |
|   Monday 08:00-09:00 |        (null) |   (null) |           2 |      08:00 |    09:00 |
|   Monday 09:00-10:00 |        (null) |   (null) |           2 |      09:00 |    10:00 |
| Thursday 11:30-12:30 |        (null) |   (null) |           5 |      11:30 |    12:30 |
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Class_Date` (such as `'Monday 09:00-10:00'`) does never *equal* `'Monday'`, but it is like `'Monday%'`:

```
SELECT
  class_time_id,
  class_id,
  class_date
FROM school.dbo.class_time_table
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Monday%' THEN 2 
  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Tuesday%' THEN 3 
  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Wednesday%' THEN 4 
  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Thursday%' THEN 5 
  WHEN class_date LIKE 'Sunday%' THEN 1 
END
```